# custom div attributes in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf

I'm using JSF 1.2 and I would like the following div to be rendered, where the latitude and longitude are stored in the backing bean

```
<div id="divMap" latitude="123456789" longitude="123456789"></div>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `escape="false"` parameter of `<h:outputText>`.

**An example**

*In your JSF:*

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.divMap}" escape="false" />
```

*In your bean:*

```
public class MyBean() {
    private String divMap;

    public MyBean() {
        ...

        //set the value of divMap here or in an actionListener. The below is just an example.
        divMap="<div id=\"divMap\" latitude=\""+latitude+"\" longitude=\""+longitude+"\"></div>";
    }

    public void setDivMap(String divMap) {
        ...
    }
    public String getDivMap() {
        ...
    }
}
```